# Self Adhesive Velcro Tape; Use one large piece or multiple small ones?

Tags: duct-tape, mosquitoes

I'm trying to apply velcro tape to my windows in order to put a mosquito net on them. So far it's fallen off twice.

So I've been thinking. If I were to use multiple small pieces of a few cm each (around 10cm long) instead of a long one to cover a whole window side, would that last better? Basically cutting a 1 meter piece of tape into 10 pieces of 10cm long tape.

The small ones would be put exactly next to each other, so it still covers the whole window. The question is would this actually improve the situation or make it even more likely to fall off?

Comment: Has the adhesive in the tape failed, and the tape came off the window? Or did the Velcro fail, and the netting became detached (but the tape remained on the window)?

Comment: What's your reasoning here? Typically more edges mean mean more points of failure.

Comment: Make sure you thoroughly clean the area that you're adhering the Velcro to. Any dust or oils will keep it from sticking very well.

Comment: Google "FlexScreen".

Answer (score 1):

We need more information on what exactly is failing, I am guessing the failure is the sticky side of the Velcro.  I would use a couple of small nails with a head to nail the Velcro in place.    Take the sticky out of the equation and come up with a way to attach the Velcro is a stronger way to the window frame.

Comment: Staples would work as well or better than nails for the purpose of holding down flat material.